# How to combine/separate multiple json

Tags: java, android

i have a json which contains 2 json Objects

```
 {"cityList":[{"id":"2","cityName":"value"}]}
 {"subGuildList":[{"id":"340","guildId":"144","subGuildName":"value"}]}
```

now i want to combine 2 jsons object to one.
What is the integration of the two json object above?
and how can i to separate main json object with java or android?

Comment: Are you trying to encode them into one object?

Comment: hi, no, i just want to merge/separate my web service transfer json to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or some similar json converter. your `Json` in incorrect. if you say 1 json contains those 2 object then it's rep should be:

```
{
   "cityList":[{"id":"2","cityName":"value"}],
   "subGuildList":[{"id":"340","guildId":"144","subGuildName":"value"}]
}
```

Your `POJO` will be:

```
public class MyObject {
    private List<MyCity> cityList;
    private List<MyGuid> subGuidList;
}

public class MyCity {
    int id;
    String cityName;
}
```

Comment: is kind of MyCity and MyCity JSONObject?

Comment: they are the pojos that represents the json that is inside the `JsonArray`

Comment: @user3404171 No, they're regular classes. GSON is a library which can convert between JSON and normal objects (aka "Plain Old Java Objects" or "POJOs")